# Custom template support for Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

Joomla is pretty good CMS but, is there any way to create custom template which will be joomla supportable ?

Comment: http://www.phpeveryday.com/pack/Joomla-Template-Step-By-Step-Tutorial
use this

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question you want to convert an existing template that isn't even a Joomla template. If that is the case I found it very hard to do, of course depending on where the template was coming from. I ended up taking a template for Joomla 1.5 and starting from that. (Although the ja_Purity is a messy one when it comes to the CSS, looking back I would should have started with another one....)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Copy default template which comes with Joomla and customize it, and you can install it now.

Refer : http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorials_Project

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [SiteGround](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla_templates.htm) tutorial.

1st result for Google: `joomla change template`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a page-specific template, then this is answered here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_template_to_a_specific_page%3F

It describes the following steps:

> In Joomla! there is a default
>   template, but you can assign other
>   templates to specific "pages" that are
>   defined by menu links.
>
> To assign a template to a page, you
>   must first make sure that there is a
>   direct menu link to the page.
>
> 1. Go to Extensions>>Template Manager
> 2. Select the Template and click the edit icon (or click the template name)
> 3. In the left column, change "None" to "Select from List."
> 4. Select the links you want to apply the template to.
> 5. Save
>
> Note that you cannot assign the
>   default template to individual pages.