# How to apply own template on Joomla?

Tags: joomla1.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom template support for Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876322/custom-template-support-for-joomla)

I have my own template which is currently not in the same pattern as that of JOOMLA Template & I want to apply my own template on Joomla.

But I don't know that how I can do it..?